# How to use query value from [[def get_queryset(self)]] and use in all classes

Tags: django

search.html file

```html
    <div class="content-section">
        <h1 class="mb-3">{{ user.username }}</h1>
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'doctor:search' %}">
                <input name ="q" value="{{request.GET.q}}" placeholder="search..">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

`VIEWS.py` 
How can i use [[query = self.request.GET.get('q')_]] once and use it's result in other class?
Currently i'm using search.html repeatedly to get 'query' value for all other classes. Where value of 'query' is same for all the classes.

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
        model = User
        template_name = 'all_users/doctor/search_result.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=query))
        return object_list

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'all_users/doctor/post_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'comment']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.patient = User.objects.get(username=query)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: you mean you want to use the search field on all templates?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Currently i'm using search.html to get the username into class views. So it is required to manually enter username in search.html for each class views. All i want to know is how to use search.html once and use its query value in all other class views.

Comment: @user6837382 is it possible to save SearchResultsView 'query' value in some kind of cache so it can be used again in another class?